# How to calculate 3D orientation of an object

Tags: opencv

How can i calculate the 3d orientation of an object from an image,a rigid body which made up of few spheres,that is my object. If i know the radius and distance from camera. how will i calculate how its oriented in 3d space?

Comment: The orientation of a sphere ?

Comment: i have few spheres in the image which together is an artifact. i would like to find the orienation of that artifact using the details i have

Comment: could you be more specific about what details you have?  Have you identified the locations of these "spheres" in your image already?

Comment: @Hammer i have intrinsic and extrinsic matrix calculated from the calibration and the distance from the camera. sphere is having know parameters, ie size is know already.

Comment: So you have the orientation of the camera relative to the model (extrinsic matrix) and you want to know the orientation of the model relative to the camera?  Or is your extrinsic matrix relative to something other than the model?

Comment: @Hammer yea i want to know the orientation of the model relative to camera.

Comment: If you have [A] with respect to [B] and you want [B] with respect to [A] you can just take the inverse of your pose.

Comment: @Hammer thank you for the tip. i was confused now have a better idea, also i assumed that my camera is in the origin.